# Is there a way to filter geoserver vector tile on request?

Tags: geoserver, mapbox, vector-tiles

I am using Geoserver 2.11.1 with the vector tile extension to render data in mapbox-gl. I'm able to pull the vector tiles in no problem, but I also need to filter the data on the server side.

```
        map.addSource('testLayer', {
            "type": 'vector',
            "scheme": 'tms',
            "tiles": ["http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/dashboard%3Atest_layer@EPSG%3A900913@pbf/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"],
        });

        map.addLayer({
            "id": "testLayer",
            "type": "circle",
            "source": "testLayer",
            "source-layer": "test_layer",
            "paint": {
                "circle-color": "#3887be"
            },
            'minzoom': 12
        });
```

I've tried adding a cql filter as a parameter in the request, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
 CQL_FILTER=account_no%20%3D%3D%202
```

Is it possible to filter vector tile data is geoserver using this kind of tms request? If no, is there a way to use WMS request with cql filter for vector tiles?

Answer (score 3):

As of GeoServer 2.11.1, nope. You can track this ticket:
https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-8065

Comment: Do you know if there is another way using a wms request?

Comment: Nope, I don't think there is any other way.

Comment: It seems like the ticket as of 2.13 Version has been solved?! If so, how do we provide cql_filler?
I tried adding parameter at the end, but the result doesn't changes.

url + "@EPSG:900913@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf?CQL_FILTER=year=2012"

Comment: @lujjas did you find solution? I am looking for same.

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari it's been a long time ago, but remember I have avoided using CQL_FILTER since it is not secured. Instead I created number of layers with the same layer name using [SQL Views](https://docs.geoserver.org/2.22.x/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html) by changing WHERE clause in different workspaces. One workspace acted as one role, therefore users having different roles had access to the same layer name, but different workspace.
[Geoserver Token Auth Plugin](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/authkey/index.html) helped in cummunication between my app and geoserver